# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) when using PHP+MySQL in openshift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

i have upload my web application to OpenShift.
my application is using the PHP and MySQL Cartridges.

i have created a few databases using PHPmyAdmin (Through the openshift web interface). each database has it's own unique name obviously.
in my PHP code i initialize the connection to one of my MySQL databases in this fashion:

```
$mysql_database=<some data base>;

$connection = mysqli_connect(getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'), getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'), getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'), "$mysql_database", getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $connection);
```

then somewhere else i am doing some queries from my PHP code (like select , update and so on) on tables inside the database i connected to. for example:

```
$query_run=mysql_query("SELECT * from `$some_table` WHERE `id`='$id'")
```

the connection itself does not fail on anything, however all my queries fail on :

```
  Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

When i manually issue these commands on the actual machine everything runs fine. so this works: SSHing into my machine using PuTTy , and doing :

```
   mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -P $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT -p <some data base>  

    mysql>SELECT * from `<some table>` WHERE `id`='<some id>'
```

i did not modify the security settings of anything, neither did i change the username / password that were generated for me for the MySQL actions.

also, everything runs perfectly fine on my local application running on a xampp Apache+MySQL server.

any ideas?

Comment: `var_dump(getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'))` what say?

Comment: is shows the correct host ip: "127.2.20.2"

Comment: I know you connect to `mysqli` but use `mysql`  `mysql_query` use correct extensions

Comment: thanks, i think that was it.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be using `mysql_query()` like that (see [Is this query safe from sql injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040174/is-this-query-safe-from-sql-injection))

You can use a much better abstraction: PHP Data Objects [(PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). e.g.

```php
try {
    // Set your connection variables
    $host = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
    $port = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT');
    $username = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
    $password = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
    $dbname = 'database_name';

    // Create the connection string
    $conn_str = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"
    // And create a db handler with PDO
    $dbh = new PDO($conn_str, $username, $password);
    // Prepare whatever statement, could also be SELECT etc
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    // Binding parameters like this prevents SQL Injection
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    // Assign values to the variables
    $name = 'Random';
    $value = 1;

    // Finally, execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Print out whatever error we got
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Don't forget to close the connection
$dbh = null
```

Not only this is a better solution for handling MySQL databases with PHP, but hopefully it will also fix your authentication problems (or make them easier to debug, at least).

Comment: @user3444042 hopefully this will also fix your authentication problem

Answer (score 0):

Stop and Start your application (not a restart).  Sometimes apache needs to be restarted to pick up the new mysql environment variables.

Comment: ok, i tried that (rhc app-stop/app-start) after the start command returned with '<application name> started', i am still getting the same behavior